# Load data to redshift from ec2 without uploading to s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am developing a java program and is looking to **load data to redshift table directly from ec2**. I know s3 is a storage location. About ec2 I know only that ec2 instance is a like a virtual machine. I am now loading data from s3. Now I want to know **how to load data from ec2 without the help of s3**.

Please help I am new to this

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do so. Since your question is too broad, I can only give relevant links from Redshift documentation:

- Explanation of the solution: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/loading-data-from-remote-hosts.html
- SQL reference of the Copy command: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-source-ssh.html

Comment: I have already read that. But it says about a manifest file which is needed in s3 and need to specify its location. Can we save the csv data file which is to be loaded in ec2 and load data from ec2 without usin s3 path. Can you explain with sample code in java

Answer (score 0):

You cannot COPY from ec2 without the help of s3.  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-source.html

You would have to connect to redshift from ec2 and perform INSERT queries.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method (though not better) is to insert the values as literals from SQL.  It is not better b/c this is a highly inefficient data transfer method but for small data payloads works just fine.

```
Insert into <table> values 
    ('A', 1, 9),
    ('B', 2, 8),
    ('C', 3, 7);
```

Again, this is NOT a good method for transferring even moderate amounts of data.  There is also SQL character length limit of 64K characters but if you are running up against this you are using this for too much data.  The best method for moving large amounts of data to Redshift is COPY from S3.